# How can I avoid repeated if-statement?

Tags: java, optimization, if-statement

I write a java application to handle log file had millions of line
In program there is such a pseudo code

```
if(optionA is On)
  call object A's method

if(optionB is On)
  call object B's method

if(optionC is On)
  call object C's method
...
```

The options in IFs are config value get from a config file
This pseudo code called in each log line, so it called millions of time

Because of speed and simplicity, I want to remove this multi IFs.
To see such a many IFs are unpleasant to me.
Is theare a good way to get around this annoying IFs?

Comment: Are you worried about 1) the scalability of the approach (you keep adding `if` statements), 2) the aesthetics of the approach (you don't want to read all those statements), 3) the performance of the approach (it's too slow), or some combination of these?  If you're clearer **why** you want to reduce the number of `if`s, we can probably help out more

Comment: Dont know java but cant you use an interface/virtual methods and use a list both for the objects and options.. Something like ``for(i=0;i<objectlist.count();i++) if(option[i])objectlist[i].method();``

Answer (score 1):

If the objects share a common interface, you could create a method like this:

```
private void callOptional(myInterface obj, boolean flag) {
  if (option) obj.method();
}
```

That way you have eliminated the IFs. But you still have a long list of common code. To make it more DRY, I'd add the object reference to the list where you store the options and then just do a for loop:

```
for (OptionObjectPair ooPair : optionObjectList) {
  callOptional(ooPair.obj, ooPair.flag)
}
```

You can then even change the interface of the callOptional method to take an OptionObjectPair directly.

Comment: Uhu, an object call in vain for each object not having their option-on, being optimization? Java is funny?

Comment: @stefan: Yeah, it's not as if the JVM would inline methods - no, don't worry we're only doing 40year old optimizations, not the 30year old ones :p

Answer (score 0):

If the method is the same for all objects, then create a option-to-object hash table and call the method based on the option.

```
HashMap<Option,ActionObject> map ;
for (Option option: map.keySet()) {
    if (optionIsTrue(option)) {  
        map.get(option).performAction() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a hashmap and not just an array/vector?

Comment: this solves only half of the problem: he has to call `performAction()` only when an `Option` instance is true

Comment: @stefan, becoz if u use an array, u will have to keep two arrays, and map from option to object based on the index.

Comment: @marcos, the second line can be put into a for loop. i am editing my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Long sequences of `if` statements are not *always* a bad thing. If you want to do it *the right way* though, you have to define the mapping of your options to their "handlers" in a data structure instead of hardcode it in if statements.

You can define a one-method interface and have `A`, `B` and `C` (in your example) implement it:

```
public interface OptionHandler { // For lack of a better name...
    void handleOption(); // You could pass parameters here
}
```

You can then define a map of the options to their handlers:

```
private final Map<Option, OptionHandler> optionHandlers = new HashMap<Option, OptionHandler>();
```

You would then replace your sequence of `if` statements with something like:

```
for (Option option : options) {
    if (!option.isOn()) {
        // Skip off option
        continue;
    }
    OptionHandler handler = optionHandlers.get(option);
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.handleOption();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you want to optimize (see templatetypedef's comment). If you just want to reduce code footprint you may do something like this

```
// let's assume you have an Option interface with isTrue() method
// let's assume you have an Action interface with performAction() method

Map<Option,Action> actions = new HashMap<Option,Action>();
// initialize actions with instance of your objects so that you have:
// optionA -> actionA
// optionB -> actionB
// etc.
// this is done only once

Option[] currentOptions;
// read the current option values and put them in an array
for (int i = 0; i < currentOptions.lengt; i++) {
    if (currentOptions[i].isTrue())
        actions.get(currentOptions[i]).performAction();
}
```